# Jquery Cycle2 only displays single image

Tags: wordpress, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I'll start this by saying I'm not super familiar with Cycle2, just that a company I'm doing work for happens to be using it on their website.

Anyway, it's not displaying multiple images in the carousel any longer, not sure why. It's a WordPress integration.

http://www.wolfbrewingcompany.com/beers/core-range/

And here's the code from the page calling the slider

```
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/jquery.cycle2.swipe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/ios6fix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.beers-slideshow').cycle();

        //$('.beers-slideshow .beer_name').hide();
        $('.beers-slideshow img')
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).parent().next().show();
        })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).parent().next().hide();

        });

    });
    </script>

    <div class="beers_bg">
    <div class="beers_wrapper">

            <?php 
                $count = 0;
                $html = '';
                if( have_rows('beer_slider') ):
                while ( have_rows('beer_slider') ) : the_row();

                $html .= '<div>
                    <a href="'.get_sub_field('beer_url').'"><img src="'.get_sub_field('beer_image').'" width="270" height="530" alt="'.get_sub_field('beer_name').'" /></a>
                    <div class="cycle-overlay">
                        <div class="beer_name">'.get_sub_field('beer_name').'</div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                $count ++;
                endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>

            <div class="beers-slideshow" 
            data-cycle-fx="carousel"
            data-cycle-timeout="0"
            data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
            data-cycle-slides="> div" 
            data-cycle-carousel-visible="<?php echo $count < 3 ? $count : 3 ?>"
            data-allow-wrap="false"
            data-cycle-carousel-fluid="false"
            data-cycle-swipe="true"
            data-cycle-next=".beers-next"
            data-cycle-prev=".beers-prev"
            >
            <?php echo $html ?>
        </div><!-- end of .beers-slideshow -->

        <?php if ($count > 3): ?>
        <span class="beers-prev"></span>
        <span class="beers-next"></span>
        <?php endif ?>

    </div><!-- end of .beers_wrapper -->
    </div><!-- end of .beers_bg -->

</div><!--  end of div post -->
```

It should be displaying 3 beer, and scrolling through.

Answer (score 0):

You can check 3 things :

1. Have you included carousel cycle2 additionnal plugin ? http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/
2. It seems Cycle2 carousel is only compatible with jquery1. What is your jquery version ?
3. Make sure you load carousel plugin AFTER cycle2

Comment: jquery is 1.9.2, and carousel is loaded after cycle2.